# Copy CC Tray Build Project List

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, cctray

Where does CC Tray store your build list?

I'm moving to a new machine and don't want to manually add my 50+ projects I monitor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm using CCTray version 1.4.1.3797, and the settings are in %APPDATA%\cctray-settings.xml

I'm on Vista, so %APPDATA% expands to C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming